Access the posts that can be viewed by logged in user using Facebook OAuth
I am trying to create an application where the application requires access to the Facebook posts(along with post title, posted date, author, all comments and replies). I was looking at the Permissions Reference for Meta Technologies APIs and I noticed a permission named user_posts that allows access to posts that user has made on their timeline. But I want access to any post(with all info like title, date, comments, etc.) that the user has access to. The user needs to copy and paste the url of the Facebook post to my application and I need to get access to the information on that post and work with it to give the desired output to the user.
Is this possible using Facebook OAuth? If not, is there any other way I can accomplish this?

You don't get access to other user's posts, unless those users had also granted your app permission to access their posts. And for access to posts on pages your user doesn't have admin access to, you would need to get the Page Public Content Access feature approved for your app.
